# LINQ generating sub query for a simple order by

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm having trouble understanding why the SQL output has a sub-query for a simple query I wrote in LINQ. This is my code:

```
var list = db.User.Where(u => u.Name == somename).OrderBy(u => u.IdUser).ToList();
```

where *somename* is a parameter I'm passing at execution time.

The output SQL is:

```
SELECT
Project1.IdUser, 
Project1.Name
FROM (SELECT
Extent1.IdUser, 
Extent1.Name
FROM user AS Extent1
WHERE Extent1.Name = 'John' /* @p__linq__0 */) AS Project1
ORDER BY 
Project1.IdUser ASC
```

Should the output really have a sub-query for something that simple?

I also tried

```
var list = db.User.Where(u => u.Name.Equals(somename)).OrderBy(u => u.IdUser).ToList();
```

which generates the same output as above.

If I hard code the parameter, like:

```
var list = db.User.Where(u => u.Name == "John").OrderBy(u => u.IdUser).ToList();
```

It works as expected, generating only

```
SELECT
Extent1.IdUser, 
Extent1.Name
FROM user AS Extent1
WHERE 'John' /* @gp1 */ = Extent1.Name
ORDER BY 
Extent1.IdUser ASC
```

A few things I'm using:

- EntityFramework 5, .NET 4.5
- SQL Server 2012
- Glimpse (which uses MiniProfiler) to see the SQL generated

I'm not a LINQ expert, so what am I missing here?

Comment: Is there any difference in query plan between the two?

Comment: No, they resolve to the same execution plan, but this syntax bugs me. Imagine if I'm debugging a more complex query generated by LINQ with all that unnecessary complexity, it wouldn't be productive.

Comment: Abstraction comes with a cost. If you don't like the cost, then write the SQL yourself. There's no right or wrong side out of these choices.

Comment: So this sub-query is expected for such a simple query? Can you elaborate on why it does this?
I understand abstraction comes with a cost, I'm trying to figure if I'm doing something wrong because, as I said, I'm not a LINQ expert.

Comment: No, I've no idea what Linq will generate for anything. If it's fast enough I use it. If it's too slow, I try and optimize (which can be difficult due to the query bloat) and if I can't then I drop down to SQL.

Comment: Probably nobody outside the EF team can answer this. I _think_ though that the team (justifiably) pursues _correct_ queries at all costs. (Correct as in producing the right results). Trying to generate the shortest possible query is probably hardly reconcilable with correctness. Apparently this works: I have yet to find the first EF LINQ query producing wrong results (with Sql server that is). So if you see these queries, thank God (or the EF team) that at least they are correct.

Comment: use your field somename by declaring inside let.. you know linq query right (not lambda )??

Comment: You don't do anything wrong with your LINQ query. The generated SQL is rarely the same that you would write by hand. Don't worry about this as long as you don't see serious performance problem. It's interesting though that the parametrized query is different from the unparametrized one. I never noticed that.

Answer (score 2):

As other pointed, the query results in same execution plan as yours. Entity Framework (and LINQ to Entites) is here to help you avoid writing SQL and bothering about SQL (to some extent). Under normal circumstances you don't care about SQL being generated nor you "debug" it. You just care whether the LINQ query is correct. Entity Framework (should) translates it into correct (sometimes even expected) SQL (and again, execution plan matters).

I'm not saying that you shouldn't look at SQL for performance reasons (or better to say execution plan of that query). But that should be done *after* you identified performance problems. And you should try to write queries *simple* first, that's the way to success. Of course if you know SQL you know this world of sets is different from world of object - you can write easily fairly average query in LINQ (thanks to objects world), but this will end up as nasty SQL (sets world) because of "mismatch" between worlds.

Comment: I think it is still a valid question that unfortunately isn't answered. Perhaps today you could get the EF Core team's opinion by opening an issue.