# Dynamic LINQ OrderBy performance issue, generating nested select

Tags: performance, linq, dynamic, nested, sql-order-by

This is a method used to fetch data for a table. While the code does "work", it has become a bottleneck in our application. In some areas it can take 30 seconds to load a page.

```
var orderBy = String.IsNullOrEmpty(options.SortColumn) ? GetOrderBy<T>() : options.SortColumn;
var orderbyDirection = (options.SortDirection == SortDirection.Desc ? " descending" : "");

options.TotalSize = queryable.Count();

queryable = queryable
    .SearchProperties(options.SearchPhrase)
    .OrderBy(orderBy + orderbyDirection)
    .SetPaging(options);

return queryable;
```

On investigation I have found that when it hits the OrderBy statement is for some reason turning the query into a nested select.

an example of a query it would generate

```
{SELECT 
[Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project1].[EntryDate] AS [EntryDate], 
[Project1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Project1].[DiaryTypeString] AS [DiaryTypeString], 
[Project1].[DiaryViewType] AS [DiaryViewType], 
[Project1].[DiaryGroup] AS [DiaryGroup], 
[Project1].[ReminderDate] AS [ReminderDate], 
[Project1].[HasAttachments] AS [HasAttachments], 
[Project1].[OwnerId] AS [OwnerId], 
[Project1].[PropertyId] AS [PropertyId], 
[Project1].[TenancyId] AS [TenancyId], 
[Project1].[SupplierId] AS [SupplierId]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[EntryDate] AS [EntryDate], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Extent1].[DiaryTypeString] AS [DiaryTypeString], 
    [Extent1].[DiaryViewType] AS [DiaryViewType], 
    [Extent1].[DiaryGroup] AS [DiaryGroup], 
    [Extent1].[ReminderDate] AS [ReminderDate], 
    [Extent1].[HasAttachments] AS [HasAttachments], 
    [Extent1].[OwnerId] AS [OwnerId], 
    [Extent1].[PropertyId] AS [PropertyId], 
    [Extent1].[TenancyId] AS [TenancyId], 
    [Extent1].[SupplierId] AS [SupplierId]
    FROM [dbo].[vwDiary] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE (([Extent1].[OwnerId] = @p__linq__0) OR (([Extent1].[OwnerId] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))) AND ( NOT ((N'Work Order' = [Extent1].[DiaryTypeString]) AND ([Extent1].[DiaryTypeString] IS NOT NULL))) AND ( NOT ((N'Alert' = [Extent1].[DiaryTypeString]) AND ([Extent1].[DiaryTypeString] IS NOT NULL)))
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[EntryDate] DESC}
```

Im a bit stuck on what to do at this point, is there something wrong with how the OrderBy is implemented? are there any alternative ways to order by a dynamic column?

Comment: So if you remove the `OrderBy` expression, the SQL doesn't have the nested `SELECT` any more?

Comment: thats right, before the order by its a standard select

Comment: As pointed out in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19202589/2557128), if the query plan isn't different between the single and double `SELECT`, than it isn't an issue. Are the query plans different?

Comment: hmmmmm i have checked the query plan and it looks the same with single and nested select. but when i comment out the order by the execution is significantly faster. I shall keep digging!

Comment: Can you execute the SQL single and double select with the `ORDER BY` to see if that makes a difference? Maybe an index can be used with single `SELECT` but not nested? Otherwise, perhaps the ORDER BY actually takes time?

Comment: it looks like I may have been barking up the wrong tree. It seems to actually be the Skip and Take inside the setPaging method that is to blame for the performance issues. (Skip and take doesnt work without order by so I had to comment that out aswell when testing so i thought it was the order by causing it and assumed the skip/take was fine)

Comment: A quick check on my database seems like `Skip`/`Take` works without `OrderBy` by assuming an `ORDER BY` the entire return value, but it requires calculating `ROW_NUMBER()` over the order. I saw an interesting suggestion to use just where x > last x and take(pagesize) but I don't think that would work for `EntryDate`.